# Selecting Datastore ID in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to make a query that selects everything where the id is 6. The problem is that I cant seem to get it to work. This is what the code looks like at the moment:

```
        query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = 6")
    result = query.get()
    for result in query:
        self.response.out.write(result.username)
```

Theres no errors or anything but it just wont output the username. Has anyone had this problem before or know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the `id` value assigned by the datastore, there can only be a single entity with a given id.

How about this instead:

```
idNum = 6
# handy function the datastore API provides...
user = Users.get_by_id(idNum)
self.response.out.write(user.username)
```